# An invalid or illegal string was specified" code: "12 with Canvas On Firefox

Tags: firefox, exception, html, canvas

I am drawing a line on a canvas using the mousedown method and for some reason firefox throws an exception... The line where the exception occurs is where quadraticCurveTo() is being called. It works flawlessly on the other browsers (Chrome and Safari) but throws an exception on Firefox 3.5...

Comment: I have same error .. "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12 " Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove /* comment */ from css file.